# Someone else points his DNS to my webserver

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, abuse

I have a DNS registered at godaddy.
The name of my DNS is: www.example.com and it works perfectly.
I discovered that www.fake.de is also linking to my web server.
The problem with this is that if someone search for www.example.com,
google wont show my DNS but fake.de. Someone else is taking advance from my webserver.

Can someone please fix this?

Comment: If intentional, I would just add a new VirtualHost showing a static international _the finger_ gesture for every request. Probably it's a mistake: someone had that IP before, closed their site and didn't care to clean it up.

Comment: Why would anyone use google to search for your domain, they've already found it then; and why would that result in enisah.de being shown by google? Besides that, Esa Jokinen just beat me to state the obvious solution.

Comment: @wurtel I'm still amazed at the amount of people that goes on google and type www.foobar.com and click on the first link. Ironically enough, the first link is usually a google ad paid by www.foobar.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do much of anything to change this. You could use whois to look up the owner/contacts for the other domain, and ask them to change their DNS.

In fact, I've done the first step for you. If the owner won't play, you might be able to contact the abuse contacts.

http://whois.domaintools.com/enisah.com

> Whois Record ( last updated on 2015-04-10 )
>
> Domain Name: enisah.com
>
> Registry Domain ID:
>
> Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.1and1.com
>
> Registrar URL: http://1and1.com
>
> Updated Date:
>
> Creation Date: 2014-10-14T19:08:06Z
>
> Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2015-10-14T19:08:06Z
>
> Registrar: 1&1 Internet AG
>
> Registrar IANA ID: 83
>
> Registrar Abuse Contact Email:
>
> Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8774612631
>
> Reseller:
>
> Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
>
> Registry Registrant ID:
>
> Registrant Name: Esaleddin Kundakci
>
> Registrant Organization: Satis-Shop
>
> Registrant Street: Enscheder Str. 256b
>
> Registrant City: Gronau (Westf.)
>
> Registrant State/Province:
>
> Registrant Postal Code: 48599
>
> Registrant Country: DE
>
> Registrant Phone: +49.1633642904
>
> Registrant Phone Ext:
>
> Registrant Fax:
>
> Registrant Fax Ext:
>
> Registrant Email:
>
> Registry Admin ID:
>
> Admin Name: Esaleddin Kundakci
>
> Admin Organization: Satis-Shop
>
> Admin Street: Enscheder Str. 256b
>
> Admin City: Gronau (Westf.)
>
> Admin State/Province:
>
> Admin Postal Code: 48599
>
> Admin Country: DE
>
> Admin Phone: +49.1633642904
>
> Admin Phone Ext:
>
> Admin Fax:
>
> Admin Fax Ext:
>
> Admin Email:
>
> Registry Tech ID:
>
> Tech Name: Hostmaster EINSUNDEINS
>
> Tech Organization: 1&1 Internet AG
>
> Tech Street: Brauerstr. 48
>
> Tech City: Karlsruhe
>
> Tech State/Province:
>
> Tech Postal Code: 76135
>
> Tech Country: DE
>
> Tech Phone: +49.7219600
>
> Tech Phone Ext:
>
> Tech Fax: +49.72191374248
>
> Tech Fax Ext:
>
> Tech Email: